# brew install does not select bottle

Tags: homebrew

I am trying to install MySQL using Homebrew.

```
➜  ~ brew install mysql               
==> Downloading https://cdn.mysql.com/Downloads/MySQL-5.7/mysql-boost-5.7.19.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Users/youri/Library/Caches/Homebrew/mysql-5.7.19.tar.gz
==> cmake . -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE=-DNDEBUG -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE=-DNDEBUG -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.19 -DCMAKE_
load: 2.07  cmd: cmake 67907 running 1.22u 1.81s
load: 1.98  cmd: ruby 69196 running 0.03u 0.00s
load: 1.98  cmd: ruby 69218 running 0.01u 0.00s
load: 1.98  cmd: ruby 69236 running 0.02u 0.00s
load: 1.98  cmd: make 69256 running 0.00u 0.00s
load: 1.98  cmd: clang 69273 running 0.04u 0.01s
load: 1.98  cmd: ruby 69291 running 0.00u 0.00s
==> make
```

Why doesn’t Homebrew select a bottled version of `mysql` instead of building it from source?

Edit: i am using High Sierra last beta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There can be two reasons why you don’t get a bottle:

- You use a custom prefix and the formula doesn’t support it
- The formula doesn’t have a bottle for your OS

You fall in the second case: Homebrew doesn’t provide bottles for High Sierra. [`mysql.rb`](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/c010d3fdd3b111462e0c34f3efe4a9ec3e583af7/Formula/mysql.rb#L7-L11) only has bottles for Sierra, El Capitan, and Yosemite.

Comment: Is there a debug flag to see the exact reason that a bottle was not picked?

Comment: I don’t think so. You can use `brew info --json=v1 <formula>` to get detailed info about a formula in JSON, including the list of available bottles. You might want to dig in that to understand why you don’t get a bottle.